# How can we extract swagger apis and Request from swagger and store in excel or list the automate it by using Rest Assured

Tags: java, swagger, playwright, rest-assured

i need to know how to collect Api by automation through swagger, Request Bodys and use it in Rest Assured code or Playwright Api automation testing

i need to know the above mentioned scenario, I need to use Test Ng , Java in Eclipse i need to write a code for extracting swagger Apis and use it for Api automation

Comment: Please share a [mcve] and write a bit more carefully and clearly. It's unclear to me what you're asking.